# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 Error in setting Variable in bindparam

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to get data from DB and add string to theme and put them in another query . When I run code I've got this error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ''goldhyipPID', 'goldhyipPayStatus',
>   programName,'goldhyipLastPayout') VALUES ('1' at line 1 in
>   C:\wamp64\www\allmonitors\test.php on line 69

```
<?php
set_time_limit(3600);
require_once 'fetchdetails/func.php';
require_once 'config.php';
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `monitors`");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($result as $monitor) {
    $monitorName = $monitor['monitorName'];
    $monitorNamePID = $monitorName . 'PID';
    $monitorNameLastPayout = $monitorName . 'LastPayout';
    $monitorNamePayStatus = $monitorName . 'PayStatus';
    $siteURL = $monitor['monitorurl'];
    $pattern1GetPID = $monitor['monitorPatternGetPID'];
    $patternLastPayOut = $monitor['monitorPatternLastPayout'];
    $patternPStatus = $monitor['monitorPatternPayStatus'];
    $patterndetailsurl = $monitor['monitorDetailsLink'];
    $patterngotositesurl = $monitor['monitorPatternGoSite'];
    $content = getPageContent($siteURL);
    preg_match_all($pattern1GetPID, $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
    foreach ($matches as $pid) {
        $id = $pid[1];
        $detailsurl = $patterndetailsurl . $id;
        $gositesurl = $patterngotositesurl . $id;
        $details = getPageContent($detailsurl);
        preg_match_all($patternPStatus, $details, $status);
        $payingStatusNumber = $status[1][0];
        if ($payingStatusNumber == 4) {
            $payingStatus = 'Not Paying';
        } elseif ($payingStatusNumber == 3) {
            $payingStatus = 'Problem';
        } elseif ($payingStatusNumber == 2) {
            $payingStatus = 'Waiting';
        } elseif ($payingStatusNumber == 1) {
            $payingStatus = 'Paying';
        }
        preg_match_all($patternLastPayOut, $details, $payout);
        if (isset($payout[1][0])) {
            $payoutdate = $payout[1][0];
        } else {
            $payoutdate = ' Not Set';
        };
        $stmt2 = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM programs where :monitorNamePID=:id');
        $stmt2->bindParam('monitorNamePID', $monitorNamePID);
        $stmt2->bindParam('id', $id);
        $stmt2->execute();
        $numofupdates = $stmt2->rowCount();
        if ($numofupdates >= 1) {
            $stmt3 = $conn->prepare("UPDATE programs SET :monitorNamePayStatus=:payingstatus , :monitorNameLastPayout=:goldhyiplastpayout WHERE :monitorNamePID=:goldhyippid  ");
            $stmt3->bindParam('monitorNamePayStatus', $monitorNamePayStatus);
            $stmt3->bindParam('monitorNameLastPayout', $monitorNameLastPayout);
            $stmt3->bindParam('monitorNamePID', $monitorNamePID);
            $stmt3->bindParam('payingstatus', $payingStatus);
            $stmt3->bindParam('goldhyiplastpayout', $payoutdate);
            $stmt3->bindParam('goldhyippid', $id);
            $stmt3->execute();
            echo 'P ID Updated : ' . $id . '<br>';
        } else {
            $siteAddress = get_redirect_final_host_url($gositesurl);
            echo $siteAddress;
            $stmt3 = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO programs (:monitorNamePID, :monitorNamePayStatus, programName,:monitorNameLastPayout) VALUES (:goldhyippid, :payingstatus, :progname, :goldhyiplastpayout)');
            $stmt3->bindParam('monitorNamePID', $monitorNamePID);
            $stmt3->bindParam('monitorNamePayStatus', $monitorNamePayStatus);
            $stmt3->bindParam('monitorNameLastPayout', $monitorNameLastPayout);
            $stmt3->bindParam('goldhyippid', $id);
            $stmt3->bindParam('payingstatus', $payingStatus);
            $stmt3->bindParam('progname', $siteAddress);
            $stmt3->bindParam('goldhyiplastpayout', $payoutdate);
            $stmt3->execute();
            echo 'P ID inserted : ' . $id . '<br>';
        }
    }
    echo "Fetching $siteURL Done <br>";
}
```

I took details from sql, and add string to them, use in PDO query. When I write column name its ok but when I use Variable I got error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding a table (or column) name doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Column names shouldn't be prepended with a colon. Remove colon `:` from your column names in both `UPDATE` and `INSERT` queries. Binding a table (or column) name doesn't work.

```
$stmt3 = $conn->prepare("UPDATE programs SET monitorNamePayStatus=:payingstatus , monitorNameLastPayout=:goldhyiplastpayout WHERE monitorNamePID=:goldhyippid  ");

$stmt3 = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO programs (monitorNamePID, monitorNamePayStatus, programName, monitorNameLastPayout) VALUES (:goldhyippid, :payingstatus, :progname, :goldhyiplastpayout)');
```